# How to check if a string contains a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, substring

S0, basically, I wrote a longer program that tests me on tenses in another language. It tests me randomly based on a die rolled. However, the snippet I quoted does not work for some reason. The problem is that if I enter "present" or "future" is skips to the else part. "both" works for some reason. What am I doing wrong? It is really annoying me because I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
tenses_tested = input("Would you like to be tested on the present, future simple, or both?")

if "present" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 0
if "future" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 6
if "both" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
else:
    print("Something went wrong because this keeps coming up...")
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
```

Comment: Use else if's instead of just if's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not what happens. It successfully enters the if block depending on whether you entered "present" or "future". But then it gets to the last condition. That condition is *independent* of the first two, and the `else` applies to *that condition only*; so since the third if is false, the else will be triggered, and will overwrite the original values.

The solution is to make them all part of the same block, by using `elif`.

```
if "present" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 0
elif "future" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 6
elif "both" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
else:
    print("Something went wrong because this keeps coming up...")
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I'm somewhat unclear on when to use elif and when to use if repeatedly. What is a good was to distinguish them? I can't tell you how grateful I am for your help.

Comment: As I said, if it's all part of *the same condition*, you should use if/elif/else. Only use separate if statements if they are completely independent; ie it's possible for them *both* to be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "present" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 0
elif "future" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 6
elif "both" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
else:
    ...
```

before the else was only attached to the `if "both" ...`

by using `elif` we attach all of them to the else, and if any work it wont go in the else

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `if` statements instead of `elif` so your code is testing for all the 3 conditions. If you add a print statement in the `"present" in tenses_tested:` block for example, you will realize that it enters that block. But it also enters the future and both blocks and because what you type is != "both", it goes into else. The same happens for future but not for both because it is the last statement. This should work:

```
tenses_tested = input("Would you like to be tested on the present, future simple, or both?")

if "present" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 0
elif "future" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 6
    roll_addition = 6
elif "both" in tenses_tested:
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
else:
    print("Something went wrong because this keeps coming up...")
    roll_range = 13
    roll_addition = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to the site and the willingness of people to take a minute to help others is great! :)